# OrderBy ThenBy - Easiest way to catch remaining (equal) items?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following:

```
new[] {
    new { A = 3, B = 3 },
    new { A = 2, B = 2 },
    new { A = 2, B = 2 },
    new { A = 1, B = 1 }
}
.OrderBy(x => x.A)
.ThenBy(x => x.B)
.ToList();
```

This `List` will contain the following data, in the following order:

> [ { A=1, B=1 }, { A=2, B=2 }, { A=2, B=2 }, { A=3, B=3 } ]

How can I identify that the items `1` and `2` are equal? I want' my code to `throw` when all `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` statements have executed and there are still items that are equal (cannot be sorted).

*Note*, imagine that the items are very complex (have a lot of properties), and that there is a million `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` statements, as well as a lot of data. I'd rather avoid another iteration of the data.

Comment: Maybe a call on distinct somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified this in my question now: I'm looking for something that plays with LINQ i.e. doesn't require another iteration of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that *before* you sort.  The easiest way to identify duplicates is to use `GroupBy`.

Since you're using anonymous types you can group by the items themselves:

```
var data = 
    new[] {
        new { A = 3, B = 3 },
        new { A = 2, B = 2 },
        new { A = 2, B = 2 },
        new { A = 1, B = 1 }
    };

var groups = data.GroupBy(x => x); // works since we are using anonymous types that use value equality

if(groups.Any(g => g.Count() > 1)
{
   // throw exception
}

var result = groups.Select(g=>g.Key)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.A)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.B)
                   .ToList();
```

If you're not using anonymous types in reality then just group by the properties that you want to use to define "equality".

You can also check for consecutive duplicate "inline" using an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ThrowIfConsecutiveItemsAreEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    bool isFirst = true;
    T prev = default(T);
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(!isFirst && item.Equals(prev))
            throw new Exception();  // TODO: use a better exception type and message

        yield return item;

        isFirst = false;
        prev = item;
    }
}
```

calling the extension method *before* `ToList` to avoid multiple enumerations:

```
var query = 
    new[] {
    new { A = 3, B = 3 },
    new { A = 2, B = 2 },
    new { A = 2, B = 2 },
    new { A = 1, B = 1 }
}
.OrderBy(x => x.A)
.ThenBy(x => x.B)
.ThrowIfConsecutiveItemsAreEqual()
.ToList();
```

Comment: This increases the procedure by O(n)... I'm looking for a better way, something like `ThenWithTheRest(...)` but without a silly name.

Comment: @Simeon there is no overload of `OrderBy` that throws if duplicates are found.  If you want something that does that _while_ it orders you're going to have to roll it yourself.

Comment: @Simeon I thought about it some more and came up with a possible solution.  See my update.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I added a parameter `Action<T> action = null` and call that action with `action?.Invoke(item);` instead of throwing, to make this method (which I've dubbed `Then`) a bit more general. It's used like this: `.ThenBy(...).Then(x => throw new Exception());` and it can be used for this purpose instead: `.ThenBy(...).Then(x => listOfEquals.Add(x));`

Answer (score 0):

In order to find duplicates this way you only need to look at the previous item after sorting:

```
static IEnumerable<C> Deduplicate(this IEnumerable<C> items) {
 C last = null;
 foreach (var item in items) {
  if (last != null && last.A == item.A && last.B == item.B) {
   //duplicate, handle as you like
  }

  last = item;
  yield return item;
}
```

There are various ways of factoring this logic but that's the basic idea. I found it useful to write a helper iterator that returns me the same sequence but with the previous item for each item. With that helper you don't need to write a custom iterator anymore.